# Laravel Post method is not working because of the special characters

Tags: laravel

I am facing a very abnormal situation here.

Below are the image of simple HTML form, with input type files and text and text area.

```
<form method="POST" action="{{ route('vendor.package.store') }}" enctype="multipart/form-data">
{!! csrf_field() !!}

   <input type="text" class="form-control" id="title" name="package_name" value="{{ old('title')) }}" required>

</form>
```

When I enter "On-The-Day (OTD) Vacation In Bali Island", and hit "Submit Button", Laravel redirect me to the index page, means the below function does not trigger at all.

```
public function store(Request $request){ 
    return $request->all();
}
```

So, I tried to answer enter "(OTD)" & "On-The-Day", Laravel redirect me to the `store` function
But whenever I tried to enter "On-The-Day (OTD)", fails.
When I try to enter "-Day (OTD)", fails
When I try to enter "-DaZ (OTD)", success.

P/S: my local development can accept `On-The-Day (OTD) Vacation In Bali Island`, only in production side cannot process the word.

Appreciate if you could help

[image]

Comment: Please post your validation rules

Comment: By the way, in `<input type="text" class="form-control" id="title" name="package_name" value="{{ old('title')) }}" required>`, replace `{{ old('title')) }}` width `{{ old('package_name') }}`. There was one `)` too much and `'title'` didn't match the `name="package_name"` of the actual input field.

Comment: inktoahref - Hi ,There not validation rules

Comment: Thierry Maasdam -  `<div class="form-group">
                <label for="package_name">Package's Title <span class="text-danger-required">*</span></label>
                <input type="text" class="form-control" id="package_name" name="package_name" value="{{ old('package_name') }}" required>
            </div>`   and its not working at all.